# Disable keys in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application. I need to disable Alt+F4 and the Ctrl+Esc key combinations. Is there a way to do this in WPF? If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try overriding the [KeyDown Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.keydown.aspx):

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Alt && e.SystemKey == Key.F4 ||
        Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control && e.SystemKey == Key.Escape)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If all your action is placed inside a window, register to the [PreviewKeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.previewkeydown.aspx)-event of the window and set always the Handled-property of the event to true, if one of the desired key-combinations is pressed. Don't use the KeyDown-event. It fires often too late. Use the PreviewKeyDown.
If you have more than one window, you can think of making an attached property and register there in the handler.

Modifier Keys you can check via the Keyboard.Modifiers-property.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the windows API: `SetWindowsHookEx`

see an example here: http://geekswithblogs.net/aghausman/archive/2009/04/26/disable-special-keys-in-win-app-c.aspx

**Notice** the example is for Windows Forms but should work also in WPF with minor changes.

Comment: Could you update your answer to support WPF...? I'm in need of a WPF solution. :)

Comment: @LuvForAirplanes did you see this? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bf73c89f-9722-4342-bccd-cf71dabd05f0/setwindowshookex-in-wpf?forum=wpf

Comment: I'll check it out. Thanks a bunch! :)